# escape url in function jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to escape properly the url in the jquery function after "close:". How can i do this.
BaseUrl in a jWQuery variable, and i want to use this to build my url.

Can somebydy help me?

Thanks.

Greetz Eric

```
$('.intoLightBox, #action').colorbox({
    onLoad: function() { 
        $('div#cboxLoadingGraphic').html('<p style="padding: 14px 0 0 38px;">Een ogenblik geduld a.u.b.</p>');
    },
    transition: 'elastic',
    width: '480px',
    height: '400px',
    close: '<img src='baseUrl + '/public/images/icons/close.gif'>',
    opacity: '0.65'
});
```

Comment: you need a + sign before baseUrl

Answer (score 2):

You have missed `+` before baseUrl and use `"`

Use

```
close: '<img src="' + baseUrl + '/public/images/icons/close.gif">',
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"` instead of `'` so you can create a valid and wekk formed string, and you have missed a + before `baseUrl`.

So try:

```
$('.intoLightBox, #action').colorbox({
    onLoad: function() { 
        $('div#cboxLoadingGraphic').html('<p style="padding: 14px 0 0 38px;">Een ogenblik geduld a.u.b.</p>');
    },
    transition: 'elastic',
    width: '480px',
    height: '400px',
    close: '<img src="' + baseUrl + '/public/images/icons/close.gif">',
    opacity: '0.65'
});
```